Recursive infinite series
I've been trying to solve a riddle, and ended up on this problem:
$$B(n)=\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}B(i)\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}B(n)=\ ?$$
I have run code to verify it converges on a value which seems correct.
I've tried solving it, but didn't get far.
Any help would be appreciated.
Edit:
You can easily find B(1) and B(2), since in those case the sum defaults to zero (since it sums on no elements) and thus are not dependent on any B(n).
I'll demonstrate the three first cases:
$$B(1)=\frac{1}{1}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{-1}B(i)\right)=1+0=1$$
$$B(2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{0}B(i)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+0\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$B(3)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{1}B(i)\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+B(1)\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+1\right)=\frac{2}{3}$$

Some more context would be helpful: for example, what are $B(1)$ and $B(2)$? You can click the "Edit" button under your question to include this.

well its linear in B(1), B(2) so you only need to check three particular cases, $\lim=-\frac{2 (B(1)-3 B(2)+1)}{e}+B(1)-2 B(2)+1$

@AryamanMaithani you can find them based on the expression, i added an edit

@AccidentalFourierTransform I'm not sure what you mean by it's linear in the first two cases, could you elaborate? and how did you get to the expression you wrote? from calculating it seems to be magically correct :) how did $e$ even get there

Hint :
Let $a_n = B(n) - B(n-1).$ Then show that $a_n = - a_{n-1}/n.$
Now can you proceed to find an expression for $B(n)$ and then the limit?

I see that someone downvoted this answer, perhaps explaining the reason would be more appropriate.

I upvoted. Unexplained downvotes drive me mad.

@Infinity_hunter Thank you! I've managed to show the equality you showed, and i found the limit of B(n) by finding the sum of the infinite series of a(n) (since a(n) is the differences series), but I'm not sure how you find the expression of B(n) from the equality, could you elaborate?

Consider the sum $\sum_{k=2}^n a_k = \sum_{k=2}^{n} B(k)-B(k-1) = B(n)- B(1)$, since you know $a_n,$ you get an expression for $B(n).$
